# SH script in $PATH is not found on Linux Alpine 3.11

Tags: linux, shell-script, path, alpine-linux

I am using Alpine Linux 3.11 as a new Docker container.

I have the default `$PATH` variable, which reads:

```
echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
```

When I place a script, `wait-for` (which is a shell script starting with `#!/bin/sh`) in `/usr/local/bin` it displays fine:

```
chmod +x wait-for
mv wait-for /usr/local/bin/wait-for
ls -l /usr/local/bin/wait-for
```

produces:

```
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root          1451 May  1 16:09 /usr/local/bin/wait-for
```

It also runs when I use `sh /usr/local/bin/wait-for` to execute it.

However, when I am in `/usr/src/` and I try to run `wait-for` I get `sh: wait-for: not found`

My understanding is that because the `/usr/local/bin` directory is in `$PATH` then any script inside that directory should be called globally.

What have I misunderstood?

I can run the file from `/usr/src/` if I use `sh /usr/local/bin/wait-for`, but not if I use `/usr/local/bin/wait-for` (without `sh` prefix), which returns `sh: /usr/local/bin/wait-for: not found`.

The output of `/etc/fstab` is:

```
/dev/cdrom      /media/cdrom    iso9660 noauto,ro 0 0                          
/dev/usbdisk    /media/usb      vfat    noauto,ro 0 0
```

Comment: You understood correctly. Something else must be off. Is the script readable?

Comment: @Pikrass is there a command to test if it's readable?

Comment: Does it start working after using the command `hash -r` once? What does the `#!`-line of your script say? Does it point to a non-existing interpreter?

Comment: @Kusalananda. No, running `hash -r` makes no difference. The file starts with `#!/bin/sh`. If I move to `cd /usr/local/bin` and run `wait-for` it works there.

Comment: @alias51 What happens if you call it with the full path from within your homedir?

Comment: @bey0nd, using `sh /usr/local/bin/wait-for` works, but using just `/usr/local/bin/wait-for` results in `not found`

Comment: @alias51 Does /bin/sh exist? And what does `ls -l /bin/sh*`return?

Comment: @bey0nd yes `/bin/sh` exists. It is a fresh install of Alpine from Docker if that makes a difference?

Comment: Is the script a DOS text file created on a Windows system?

Comment: @SantoshGarole thanks, question updated.

Comment: @Kusalananda it's a clone of this file https://raw.githubusercontent.com/eficode/wait-for/master/wait-for, but I have opened it in sublime text on a windows machine.

Comment: Try running `dos2unix` on the script and then run it as `wait-for` again.

Comment: @Kusalananda, so it turns out that the `wait-for` script was using windows line endings. When I converted it to `unix` line endings, it's now recognising the file. However I am still lost as to why `sh /usr/local/bin/wait-for` worked and `/user/local/bin/wait-for` or just `wait-for` did not?

Comment: Possible duplicates:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/118159/shell-script-works-when-saved-with-nano-but-not-when-saved-with-notepad
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/224187/shell-script-error-not-found-no-such-file-or-directory

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your interactive shell is `dash` (masquerading as `sh`).  The `dash` shell says

```
sh: /usr/local/bin/wait-for: not found
```

when it tries to execute a script that has a faulty `#!`-line pointing to an interpreter that can't be found. It *happens* to be exactly the same error that you would get when the command that you type can't be found, so it's easy to think it's a `$PATH` issue (it's not in this case). Oher shells have more informative error messages (`bash` and `zsh` says "bad interpreter: No such file or directory" and also tells you what interpreter it tried to execute).

Since [the file is a DOS text file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/583822/sh-script-in-path-is-not-found-on-linux-alpine-3-11/583842#comment1087220_583822), the `#!`-line instructs the shell to run the script with `/bin/sh\r`, where `\r` is a common representation of a carriage return character, which is part of the line termination in DOS text files.  On a Unix system, a carriage return is an "ordinary character" and not at all part of the line termination, which mean that it tries to start `/bin/sh\r` to run your script, and then fails as that file does not exist.  It is therefore the *interpreter* that is "not found", not the script itself.

Running the script with an *explicit* interpreter bypasses the `#!`-line, always, which is why you don't get the error when you do that.  However, each line in the script would still have the carriage returns at the end of them, which may cause the script to malfunction under some conditions.

Simply re-saving the file as a Unix text file, or converting it with `dos2unix`, would resolve your issue.

Answer (score 1):

For those finding this question, my specific issue was somehow my `wait-for` script had converted to windows line endings.

When resaving with unix line endings this problem resolved.

If someone can post a better answer explaining why windows line endings caused the file to be recognised only when using `sh /usr/local/bin/wait-for` and not `/usr/local/bin/wait-for` or `wait-for` I will accept that.

Comment: Are you saying that when you changed `\r\n` to `\n`, you could run `wait-for` and before changing you got `file not found` error and _not_ an `/bin/bash^M: bad interpreter:` error?

Comment: @terdon Yes, exactly. I am at a loss as to why this would be the case, I did not change anything else.

Comment: I have absolutely no idea and I can't reproduce it. I even downloaded the exact same script, saved it with the same name, changed the line endings by running `sudo sed -i 's/$/\r/' /usr/local/bin/wait-for` and then ran `wait-for` and got the expected `bad interpreter` error. Can you reproduce it now? Either by running the `sed` command I gave you or by repeating your original steps (download -> open in sublime -> try to run on Linux)? I completely understand if you can't be bothered to, don't worry.

Comment: @terdon the message may be different depending on the user's interactive shell (with `dash` I get `sh: 1: ./wait-for: not found` for example)

Comment: @steeldriver that hadn't even occurred to me. Thank you, this was bugging me :)